# #if Not Debug in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have  the  line in vb code:

```
#if Not Debug
```

which I must convert, and I don't see it in c#?

Is there something equivalent to it, or is there some workaround?

Answer (score 332, accepted):

You would need to use:

```
#if !DEBUG
    // Your code here
#endif
```

Or, if your symbol is actually `Debug`

```
#if !Debug
    // Your code here
#endif
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx), you can effectively treat `DEBUG` as a boolean. So you can do complex tests like:

```
#if !DEBUG || (DEBUG && SOMETHING)
```

Answer (score 18):

Just so you are familiar with what is going on here, `#if` is a pre-processing expression, and `DEBUG` is a conditional compilation symbol. [Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a more in-depth explanation.

By default, when in **Debug** configuration, Visual Studio will check the **Define DEBUG constant** option under the project's Build properties. This goes for both C# and VB.NET. If you want to get crazy you can define new build configurations and define your own Conditional compilation symbols. The typical example when you see this though is:

```
#if DEBUG
    //Write to the console
#else
    //write to a file
#endif
```

Answer (score 17):

Just in case it helps someone else out, here is my answer.

This would not work right:

```
#if !DEBUG
     // My stuff here
#endif
```

But this did work:

```
#if (DEBUG == false)
     // My stuff here
#endif
```

Comment: Might have been right at the day this was posted, but at least for VS 2015 !DEBUG does work as expected

Answer (score 5):

I think something like will work

```
 #if (DEBUG)
//Something
#else
//Something
#endif
```

Comment: Just noting the parenthesis are not required for this conditional `#if` statements. It can be written `#if DEBUG`

Comment: Absolutely not what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended on this question when I googled, just want to add that an alternative could be

```
#if RELEASE
```

Answer (score -4):

```
     bool isDebugMode = false;
#if DEBUG
     isDebugMode = true;
#endif
    if (isDebugMode == false)
    {
       enter code here
    }
    else
    {
       enter code here
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad answer since it uses run-time logic to handle what could be done at compile time.

Comment: Design time T4 templating and the like will need this kind of thing from time to time.

Comment: the advantage of using run time over compile time is that it is infinitely easier to debug, since you don't have to recompile. It also reduces the number of versions of code you could compile, which again is easier to support. if anything, using run time logic over compile time is an advantage, though in this case I would still prefer the more concise handling

Comment: Absolutely not what was asked.